# Code first fluent api - table relationship

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, ef-code-first

I have following tables and need to set relationship between them.

[image]

Model classes for the tables are as given

```
public class UserAction
{
    public int ActionID { get; set; }
    public string ActionName { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<RoleScreenActionPermission> RoleScreenActionPermissions { get; set; }
}
 public class Screen
{
    public int ScreenID { get; set; }
    public string ScreenName { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<RoleScreenActionPermission> RoleScreenActionPermissions { get; set; }
}
public class ScreenAction
{
    public int ScreenActionID { get; set; }
    public int ScreenID { get; set; }
    public int ActionID { get; set; }

    public virtual Screen Screen { get; set; }
    public virtual UserAction UserAction { get; set; }
}
public class RoleScreenActionPermission
{
    public int RoleScreenActionPermissionID { get; set; }
    public int ScreenActionID { get; set; }
    public int RoleID { get; set; }

    public virtual ScreenAction ScreenAction { get; set; }
    public virtual Role Role { get; set; }

}
```

The talbe structure created is as:
 [image]

Please help with setting the relationship correctly.

Answer (score 2):

Try to remove all your own foreign keys from your classes. EF must make it.

upd:

```
public class Screen
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Action
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class ScreenAction
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual Screen Screen { get; set; }
    public virtual Action Action { get; set; }
}

public class RoleScreenActionPermission
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual ScreenAction ScreenAction { get; set; }
    public virtual Role Role { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Couldn't follow you exactly

Comment: Thanks a lot. Rather than removing all the foreign keys, I removed the ICollection ref from the primary tables.